# Regex: Match if the expression is present, but if the expression have specific string before it don't match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to validate some symbols in a string on a textarea control.

Currently this is my regex expression:

```
 /^(?:((?!<\\)(?!\/>)).)*$/
```

It will check for string that have /> or <\ but not / > or < \ (with space between).

What i want to accomplish is if i have for example an html tag like break (< br/>)) in the textarea it will not match the regex but if the textarea have "foobar/>" or "<\foo" then it match.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to check if a string does not contain ``< \``, why not use ``if (!s.Contains("< \\")) { return true; }``?

Comment: That's one of my options @WiktorStribiżew. But the problem is if i do that i will modify 20+ files, so i am trying to lessen the changes that i will made.

Answer (score 1):

> `regex = r"^(?<!\<)(\s*\w+\s*\/>)$|^(\<\\\s*\w+\s*)(?!\>)$"`

Above regex match starting position and ending position [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/W4gtkP/1/)
negative look-behind and negative look-ahead.

[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PU1P.png)

Comment: The question is in JavaScript. I assume your snippet is in Python?  Could you adapt it to JavaScript syntax?

Comment: This answer is what i wanted. But the other problem is since it is a text area, when i tried to enter more text after the `<\foo` or `bar/>` the expression doesn't match.

Comment: this regex is bounded by starting position(^) and end position ($).
If you really want to run with massive data then my suggestion is to replacer"<[^>]*>" with some r" | " and run these pattern r"(?<!\<)(\s*\w+\s*\/>)|(\<\\\s*\w+\s*)(?!\>)" After that r" | " to r"<>" that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can match for spaces(%) or characters (w) to help you with this. 
/\w+/>|<\\w+/g will check for foo/> and <\foo across the entire string.

The g-flag stands for global which means it will repeat itself across the string and might be implemented different in your language.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. The only solution to my problem is to add a multiline (m) flag in the regex expression.

I thought that when i tried to press enter key in the text area, it generates a hidden break tag `<br/>`

Also when i tried to paste the data from the textarea it generates a paragraph tag `<p>, <p/>` so i am trying to accomplish to remove those tags.

But since it was only a multiline flag it is now working.

This is now my regex expression.

```
 /^(?:((?!<\\)(?!\/>)).)*$/m
```

And this is the test for my expression

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/W4gtkP/2)